# How to delete a mysql row without using field names when using python and mysqldb?

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import sys
import MySQLdb
from getpass import getpass

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, passwd, db, charset = 'utf-8')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("show tables")
tablenames = [i[0] for i in cur.fetchall()]

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % tablenames)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    x = re.compile(r"\bhello\b")
    p = x.search(str(row))
    if p:
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM %s WHERE " % t) # how to delete this row

conn.close()
```

Using the code above, I would like to search the table rows with regular expressions, and search for the keyword "hello".

If it's matched, I'd like to delete the row which for loop in rows that fetched all.

How can I write the delete statement when the regular expression found the row?

Thanks very much!

Comment: That's not a row, it's a tablename (as indicated by your variable name) Do you want to DROP TABLE it or DELETE FROM all the rows in it, or something else?

Comment: that "where" line i'm not finished, i want to delete one row that fit my search condition, delete one row that i checking.

Answer (score 2):

you can use LIKE in your SQL:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `content` LIKE "%value%"
```

and important thing after executing your sql is commit:

```
a = cur.execute(sql)
con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If as I suspect you want to delete rows which meet some criteria than you don't need the select at all.
`DELETE FROM tableName WHERE columnName [=, !=, <, >, LIKE] columnValue`
If you need regex match than read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html